# Node JS (Requests Loggin In Auth) Encryption and How to do it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I try to do http request (Loggin in) with NodeJS
but before I send the POST Request to the url , there's a PreAuthenticate which response these JSON Object to me

```
{"e2ee": {
        "pseudoOaepHashAlgo": "SHA256",
        "pseudoPubKeyIndex": "0004",
        "pseudoSid": "0001nEDMjbDVqwgpjLTOKNr5_2z63SykIz2PNsKqDqEzlORG051o8drUp_8OwgXusTGzCSTlrmJMqkolMHTzb00FjEKWdds",
        "pseudoRandom": "586AADD845626E05A154DD2517F0C9B0",
        "pseudoPubKey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
    }
}
```

I THINK IT IS HEX!

it is end to end encryption or  some kind of encryption things but i don't know what it is.

and then after the client POST to login. it POST this JSON.

i think the plain text is "933444" which is the input type.

```
{
    "pseudoPin": "0001nEDMjbDVqwgpjLTOKNr5_2z63SykIz2PNsKqDqEzlORG051o8drUp_8OwgXusTGzCSTlrmJMqkolMHTzb00FjEKWdds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
    "pseudoSid": "0001nEDMjbDVqwgpjLTOKNr5_2z63SykIz2PNsKqDqEzlORG051o8drUp_8OwgXusTGzCSTlrmJMqkolMHTzb00FjEKWdds"
}
```

the question is how to encrypt the plain text (93344) to these thing (above this). it is use for loggin in . need help !

> the plain text is "933444" i try to create RSA public key to encrypt
> it. but the key it's not look similiar. the public key that response
> from preAuth only have number and upper character. –
>
> the flow might be --> get PreAuth --> get some variable from response
> --> encrypt "933444" with those variable ----> send back to login

Comment: Your question is unclear. `How to encrypt the plain text to these thing`, what do you mean? Encrypt what text, encrypt in which manner? Please write a simple and understandable question, with steps, that shows the input and desired output, what you have tried so far etc.

Comment: @JeremyThille the plain text is "933444" i try to create RSA public key to encrypt it.
but the key it's not look similiar. the public key that response from preAuth only have number and upper character.

Comment: @JeremyThille i think the flow is
--> PreAuth --> get some variable from response 
--> encrypt "933444" with those variable  ----> send back to login

Comment: I mean could you please _edit_ your original question and write all this clearly? So others can also understand what you mean and try to help.